# Is it possible to connect microcontroller pins directly to CANcaseXL from Vector?

Tags: embedded, can-bus

So that I can access the messages in the CANoe tool... This is just to test my application; I don't have a CAN transceiver on my development board.

I think there are some options.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  Get a CAN transceiver chip and solder it on to your development board.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The CANcaseXL and USB cable both work as a transceiver. So you can not directly connect them to the microcontroller. But do some R&D and try it; it may be possible. Because all the inventions came like this way only.